# Folder shared over internet by multiple users

Tags: internet, webdav, directory, share

We would like to setup a folder on a server where we would keep our documents.
This folder would be mapped to windows like a network drive where users can copy/paste documents. 
Thing is, this folder would not be on local network, it would be on a server which is accessible over internet.
We don't want dropbox or something like that...
We were thinking of webdav, but we were wondering if there is something better?

Summary:
-Folder accessible over internet by multiple users (username/password)
-Mapped as a network drive on windows xp
-No Dropbox, or dropbox variations, no FTP, no VPN

Question: Should we use WebDav or there is a better solution?

Thanks!

Comment: What type of documents are you talking about? (word/excel type only? read only PDFs?)

Comment: Hi, it would be a mix of most common file types txt/word/excel/pdfs/ppt/images, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This use case is exactly what WebDAV excels at. I'd recommend going that way unless you want the added complexity of a proper Document management system (Alfresco, Sharepoint, etc.).